# How to write custom action to delete an installed file before install finalize

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I want to write a custom action that will delete an installed file before installation is finalized, i.e after I install file "test" from msi.

I am executing it. Now I want to delete this file after it is executed. I have written a custom action for execution of "test" file. How should I write a custom action for deleting it?

Comment: If you are using an Installshield product there is a special built-in feature doing exactly what you want to do. I belive it is a view in the editor called "Support files". Files you add here are available during the installation, but get deleted when the installation is finished. If you are using another installer product I am not sure if they have the same feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can use C# for custom action development. Set according [Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d.aspx) in MSDN

Answer (score 1):

This is not recommended because Windows Installer may detect the missing file and try to repair it. Instead, you can try this approach:

- store the file in [Binary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367825%28VS.85%29.aspx) table
- use a [custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368062%28VS.85%29.aspx) to extract it in a temporary location when installation starts
- use another custom action to remove it at installation end

To extract the file you can use the [Windows Installer API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368250%28VS.85%29.aspx). You also need a DLL or VBScript custom action which receives the installation handle. Perhaps this tutorial will help:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx